# Pacemaker DRBD resource not getting promoted to master on any node

Tags: drbd, pacemaker, master-slave

First off, I'm no linux specialist, I've been following tutorials and been working with the help of google, this worked out fine until now, but currently I'm stuck with a problem.
I'm using CentOS 6.5 and DRBD version 8.4.4.

I have two nodes running pacemaker, so far everything has been working, I set up DRBD and I can manually set a node as primary and mount the DRBD resource, so that is also working.

now I created a pacemaker resource to control DRBD but it fails to promote any of the two nodes to master which also prevents it getting mounted.

pcs status looks like this:

```
Cluster name: hydroC
Last updated: Wed Jun 25 14:19:49 2014
Last change: Wed Jun 25 14:02:25 2014 via crm_resource on hynode1
Stack: cman
Current DC: hynode1 - partition with quorum
Version: 1.1.10-14.el6_5.3-368c726
2 Nodes configured
4 Resources configured


Online: [ hynode1 hynode2 ]

Full list of resources:

 ClusterIP      (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started hynode1
 Master/Slave Set: MSdrbdDATA [drbdDATA]
     Slaves: [ hynode1 hynode2 ]
 ShareDATA      (ocf::heartbeat:Filesystem):    Stopped
```

ShareData remains stopped because there is no master

I initially followed this tutorial:
http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1-pcs/html/Clusters_from_Scratch/_configure_the_cluster_for_drbd.html

this is how the pacemaker config looks:

```
Cluster Name: hydroC
Corosync Nodes:

Pacemaker Nodes:
 hynode1 hynode2

Resources:
 Resource: ClusterIP (class=ocf provider=heartbeat type=IPaddr2)
  Attributes: ip=10.0.0.100 cidr_netmask=32
  Operations: monitor interval=30s (ClusterIP-monitor-interval-30s)
 Master: MSdrbdDATA
  Meta Attrs: master-max=1 master-node-max=1 clone-max=2 clone-node-max=1 notify
=true
  Resource: drbdDATA (class=ocf provider=linbit type=drbd)
   Attributes: drbd_resource=r0
   Operations: monitor interval=60s (drbdDATA-monitor-interval-60s)
 Resource: ShareDATA (class=ocf provider=heartbeat type=Filesystem)
  Attributes: device=/dev/drbd3 directory=/share/data fstype=ext4
  Operations: monitor interval=60s (ShareDATA-monitor-interval-60s)

Stonith Devices:
Fencing Levels:

Location Constraints:
Ordering Constraints:
  promote MSdrbdDATA then start ShareDATA (Mandatory) (id:order-MSdrbdDATA-Share
DATA-mandatory)
Colocation Constraints:
  ShareDATA with MSdrbdDATA (INFINITY) (with-rsc-role:Master) (id:colocation-Sha
reDATA-MSdrbdDATA-INFINITY)

Cluster Properties:
 cluster-infrastructure: cman
 dc-version: 1.1.10-14.el6_5.3-368c726
 no-quorum-policy: ignore
 stonith-enabled: false
```

I've since tried different things like setting a location constraint or using different resource settings... I took this from another tutorial:

```
 Master: MSdrbdDATA
  Meta Attrs: master-max=1 master-node-max=1 clone-max=2 notify=true target-role
=Master is-managed=true clone-node-max=1
  Resource: drbdDATA (class=ocf provider=linbit type=drbd)
   Attributes: drbd_resource=r0 drbdconf=/etc/drbd.conf
   Meta Attrs: migration-threshold=2
   Operations: monitor interval=60s role=Slave timeout=30s (drbdDATA-monitor-int
erval-60s-role-Slave)
               monitor interval=59s role=Master timeout=30s (drbdDATA-monitor-in
terval-59s-role-Master)
               start interval=0 timeout=240s (drbdDATA-start-interval-0)
               stop interval=0 timeout=240s (drbdDATA-stop-interval-0)
```

but the result stays the same, none of the nodes gets promoted to master.

I'd appreciate any help guiding me to the solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be sure: You did start the resource ShareDATA? The DRBD resource will only get (automatically) promoted to master if there is a reason (another resource depending on it or explicitly configured).

Comment: To my knowledge ShareDATA doesn't start because there is no MSdrbdDATA Master, if I try to manually start ShareDATA via 'crm_resource --force-start' it gives me the same error as if I would try to mount the DRBD resource manually, I can't mount it because there is no DRBD primary.

Comment: "gives me the same error" - what exactly?

Comment: `[root@hynode1 ~]# crm_resource --resource shareDATA --force-start  
Operation start for shareDATA (ocf:heartbeat:Filesystem) returned 1  
 >  stderr: INFO: Running start for /dev/drbd3 on /share/data  
 >  stderr: /dev/drbd3: Wrong medium type  
 >  stderr: mount: block device /dev/drbd3 is write-protected, mounting read-only  
 >  stderr: mount: Wrong medium type  
 >  stderr: ERROR: Couldn't mount filesystem /dev/drbd3 on /share/data  `

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to format correctly in the answers  `[root@hynode1 ~]# mount /dev/drbd3 /share/data -t ext4
mount: block device /dev/drbd3 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: Wrong medium type`

Comment: hm, I would guess that MSdrbdDATA or the constraints have an error because shareDATA should not try to do anything if MSdrbdDATA is not master. Anything in the log? I'm sure that you need to define role="Slave" and role="Master" for the monitor operation for a DRBD resource. But you did this in one of your attempts...

Comment: hmm I'm not sure what I should look for, I searched for errors in /var/log/messages, but there's nothing from today ... btw the resource is now called "shareDATA" and not "ShareDATA" because I was redoing everything from scratch, so there is no lowercase/uppercase problem before anyone asks, and yes I have currently configured the monitor operations for both roles as above.

Comment: What does the DRBD device look like: `cat /proc/drbd`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your DRBD device is healthy. If you `# cat /proc/drbd` and look at it's state, do you see the following: `cs:Connected`, `ro:Secondary/Secondary`, and most importantly, `ds:UpToDate/UpToDate`?

Without `UpToDate` data, the resource agent for DRBD will NOT promote a device. If you've *just* created the device's metadata, and haven't forced a single node into the `Primary` role yet, you'll see your disk state is: `ds:Inconsistent/Inconsistent`. You'll need to run the following to tell DRBD which node should become the `SyncSource` for the cluster: `# drbdadm primary r0 --force`

That's the only time you should have to force DRBD into Primary under normal circumstances; so forget the `--force` flag after that ;)